# How to report on how many emails have been sent by sql server for a given period of time?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, senddbmail

Is there a good way to determine how many emails have been sent by sql server (sql notifications + invocations of sp_send_dbmail by applications) for a given period of time?  Need this info for billing discussions.

SQL Server 2014

Answer (score 5):

You can query the dbo.sysmail_mailitems table in the msdb database. This is the log table for sp_send_dbmail. Documentated [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sysmail-allitems-transact-sql).